# Como alterar o conteúdo de uma variável no Batch

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Estou querendo alterar os dados de uma **variável** com letras por números..

Por exemplo, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
@echo off

set /p var=Digite a variavel:
echo %var:1=a%

pause
```

Mas, se eu digitar: `123`, sua saída deverá ser: `ABC`.
Porém, a forma que estou fazendo, ele troca somente o número `1`. Desejo alterar todos os números **independente** do texto digitado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Veja se é algo assim:

```
@echo off
:Inicio
cls
echo.
set /p var=digite a variavel:

set var=%var:1=a%
set var=%var:2=b%
set var=%var:3=c%
set var=%var:4=d%
set var=%var:5=e%
set var=%var:6=f%
set var=%var:7=g%
set var=%var:8=h%
set var=%var:9=i%
set var=%var:0=j%

echo %var%
echo.
pause
goto :Inicio
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, apliquei a lógica ao meu problema e funcionou. 

Sabe como aumento o tamanho da fonte do cmd via bat? e dimensionar o tamanho da janela tbm...? mas preciso executar por dentro do bat

Comment: mode con: cols=50 lines=15 (para deixar a janela com 50 colunas "horizontal" e 15 linhas "vertical")